# Using Base Adapter for gallery in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: java, android, gallery, baseadapter

I'm a rookie developer working on a Quiz app but with some additional features such as rewards (collectibles). The idea is that after the user finishes a quiz, they get a card (a picture of the hero) as a reward and then they can check those in a sort of a gallery. But my problem is with the gallery itself.
The Gallery widget is no longer supported so I wanted to use standard Horizontal Scroll view.
It should look like this:

[image: Layout]

At the bottom, you can see the scroll view, where the cards should be displayed and you can swipe between them left-right. If you tap the card, it will be displayed in the IV. Also there is a TV for some info, but that's not relevant now.
The problem is I can't use Base Adapter to fill the images into ScrollView (*setAdapter*).
I know it can be done using ListView or GridView but I wanted the gallery be like this (Horizontal)
I even tried it using **ViewPager**, but that doesn't work either (also I'm not sure if ViewPager is good a way to do this). When I've tried ViewPager insted ScrollView (*viewPager.setAdapter(cardGalleryAdapter);*), I got an error that an Adapter is required and not my custom Base Adapter.
Am I missing something? Or is there any other way how to do this?
Also I should mention that I'm doing this in fragment, not activity itself, could that be the issue?
My code:

Adapter Class:

```
public class CardGalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private int [] cards;

    public CardGalleryAdapter(Context c, int [] images){
        context = c;
        this.cards = images;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cards.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setImageResource(cards[position]);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        return imageView;
    }
```

}

Fragment Class:

```
public class DeckFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

HorizontalScrollView gallery;
ImageView cardView;
TextView cardText;
CardGalleryAdapter cardGalleryAdapter;
DeckCards deckCards;
ViewPager2 viewPager;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Getting objects
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_deck, container, false);
    //Gallery as HorizontalScrollView it not working
    gallery.findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    gallery.setOnClickListener(this);
    cardView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    cardText.findViewById(R.id.cardText);
    viewPager.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    //Separate class, where the array of the cards is located
    deckCards = new DeckCards();
    cardGalleryAdapter = new CardGalleryAdapter(getContext(), deckCards.getCards());
    //ViewPager instead HorizontalScrollView, but I get the mentioned error
    viewPager.setAdapter(cardGalleryAdapter);
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
```

}

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you want to scroll items in a horizontal manner in the below view. You can use Recyclerview and create an adapter for the same. Make sure you set the orientation horizontal to Recyclerview.

Refer to this: [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#:~:text=RecyclerView%20is%20the%20ViewGroup%20that,by%20a%20view%20holder%20object](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#:%7E:text=RecyclerView%20is%20the%20ViewGroup%20that,by%20a%20view%20holder%20object).